# All sums of a number

Tags: algorithm, pascal, freepascal

I need an algorithm to print all possible sums of a number (partitions).
For example: for 5 I want to print:

```
1+1+1+1+1

1+1+1+2

1+1+3

1+2+2

1+4

2+3

5
```

I am writing my code in Pascal. So far I have this:

```
Program Partition;

Var
  pole :Array [0..100] of integer;
  n :integer;

{functions and procedures}
function Minimum(a, b :integer): integer;
Begin
  if (a > b) then Minimum := b
             else Minimum := a;
End;

procedure Rozloz(cislo, i :integer);
Var
  j, soucet :integer;
Begin
    soucet := 0;

    if (cislo = 0) then
    begin
        for j := i - 1 downto 1 do
        begin
           soucet := soucet + pole[j];

           if (soucet <> n) then
              Write(pole[j], '+')
           else Write(pole[j]);
       end;
       soucet := 0;
       Writeln()
   end

                   else
   begin
       for j := 1 to Minimum(cislo, pole[i - 1]) do
        begin
            pole[i] := j;
            Rozloz(cislo - j, i + 1);
        end;
   end; 
End;
{functions and procedures}

{Main program}
Begin
    Read(n);
    pole[0] := 101;
    Rozloz(n, 1);

    Readln;
End.
```

It works good but instead of output I want I get this:

```
1+1+1+1+1

2+1+1+1

2+2+1

3+1+1

3+2

4+1

5
```

I can't figure out how to print it in right way. Thank you for help

**EDIT:** changing `for j:=i-1 downto 1` to `for j:=1 to i-1` solves one problem. But my output is still this: (1+1+1+1+1) (2+1+1+1) (2+2+1) (3+1+1) (3+2) (4+1) (5) but it should be: (1+1+1+1+1) (1+1+1+2) (1+1+3) (1+2+2) (1+4) (2+3) (5) **Main problem is with the 5th and the 6th element**. They should be in the opposite order.

Comment: Is the only thing that's wrong the order? you want increasing order instead of decreasing?  If that's the case, I think you can just change the "for j:=i-1 downto 1" from counting down, to counting up... from 1 to i-1.  Your algorithm appears to just find the largest numbers first (because this j starts large).

Comment: This solves one problem, but my output is still this:
(1+1+1+1+1)

(2+1+1+1)

(2+2+1)

(3+1+1)

(3+2) 

(4+1)

(5)

but it should be: 
(1+1+1+1+1)

(1+1+1+2)

(1+1+3)

(1+2+2)

(1+4)

(2+3)

(5)


Problem is also with the 5th and the 6th element. They should be in the opposite order.

Comment: Do not add additional details in comments. They can't be properly formatted, and they're not in the question where they can easily be seen (and where they belong). Please [edit] your question to include the details there instead.

Comment: I am sorry. I have edited my question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the order that you're looking for.  Perhaps you could state clearly what the order is that you're looking for.  3+2 would come alphabetically before 4+1, so it seems they are in alphabetical order (lexical).  I'm not sure what order you intend.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes, it should be in lexicographical order.
With my code I get: 4+1 **before** 3+2, so it is not lexicographical.

Comment: So do you want the numbers in the sum in increasing order, and the each block in lexicographical order?  You could always just dump all the terms to a file (or array) and sort them after you've generated the whole list.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that - numbers in sum in increasing order and each block lexicographical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't attempt Pascal, but here is pseudocode for a solution that prints things in the order that you want.

```
procedure print_partition(partition);
    print "("
    print partition.join("+")
    print ") "

procedure finish_and_print_all_partitions(partition, i, n):
    for j in (i..(n/2)):
        partition.append(j)
        finish_and_print_all_partitions(partition, j, n-j)
        partition.pop()
    partition.append(n)
    print_partition(partition)
    partition.pop()

procedure print_all_partitions(n):
    finish_and_print_all_partitions([], 1, n)
```

Comment: None of what you included as "pseudocode" has anything to do with Pascal, and therefore is not an answer to the question asked here.

Comment: @KenWhite The request was for an algorithm, not code.  The pseudocode that I gave expresses an algorithm which is translatable into any imperative language that supports recursion, including Pascal.  Therefore it is an answer to the question as asked.

Comment: This poster clearly isn't capable of translating that pseudocode into Pascal; they're having trouble arranging output of the existing code (which is what the question is actually asking, if you read more than the first four words of the opening sentence). Your answer says "Well, I won't attempt to answer your question about A, but I'll give you some text that isn't related that vaguely discusses Z".